# How to populate circle type percentage validation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have five input fields, I need to validate all the fields by showing a circle type validation modal. It will be incremented dynamically.

Please find attached sample validation images.

[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]

Here is the code:

```
$("#field1, #field2, #field3").blur(function() {
    var getImageName = $('#step-dwld').attr('src').slice(7, 30);
    if( !this.value ){
            $('#step-dwld').attr('src', 'images/'+getImageName);
    } else{
    switch (getImageName) {
        case "step-bg.png":
            $('#step-dwld').attr('src', "images/step-1.png"); 
            break;
        case "step-1.png":
            $('#step-dwld').attr('src', "images/step-2.png"); 
            break;
        case "step-2.png": 
            $('#step-dwld').attr('src', "images/step-3.png"); 
            break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of your vague question without or with very less code it is hard for us to guess what your code is and your HTML structure, you need to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can help you.

However check this it might give you an idea on how to do it, I don't now your code this why and based on guesswork I implemented a similar one to simulate it

[**JS Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/rrne994y/)

```js
var validate = $('.validate'), score= 0;

validate.on('change', function(){
 score = 0;
 validate.each(function(){
   if($(this).val() != ''){
     score += 100 / validate.length;
    }
    console.log(score);
    setImage(score);
  });
});

function setImage(score){
    var url;
    switch (score){
        case 20:
            url = '20%';
            break;
     
        case 40:
         url = '40%';
            break;
      
        case 60:
         url = '60%';
            break;
      
        case 80:
            url = '80%';
        break;
      
        case 100:
            url = '100%';
            break;
      
        default:
           url = '0%';
    }
    var img = '<img src="//placehold.it/100x100/?text=' +url+ '">';
    $('#img').html(img);
}
```

```css
#img{width:100px;height:100px;border:1px solid gray;margin:10px 0;}
input[type="text"]{display:block;margin:2px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="img"></div>
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text" class="validate">
<input type="text" class="validate">
<button id="done">I'm Done!</button>
```